# JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String ,and in axioms when sending it began with Bearer

Tags: javascript, java, axios

I'm trying to send a post request sending the token in the header and also as a string. The problem is authenticating the header in the backend gives me the error `JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String`.

Below is the relevant code.

**Frontend**

```
    getUser() {
        if (token != null) {
            const config = {
                headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
            };

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.set("token", token);
            
            axios.post("http://localhost:8080/user/token", formData,config)
                .then((function (response) {
                    if (response.data.email !== null) {

                        sessionStorage.setItem("role", response.data.role);
                        sessionStorage.setItem("userId", response.data.id);
                        sessionStorage.setItem("name", response.data.name);

                        location.reload(true)
                        document.getElementById('loginResult').innerHTML = response.data.token;
                    }

                }));
        }

    }
```

**Backend**

```
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
              // We don't need CSRF for this example
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
              // dont authenticate this particular request
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/events").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/events/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","VENDOR")
                .antMatchers("/event-photos/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","VENDOR")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
             // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
             // store user's state.
               .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

             // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
```

```
    @PostMapping("user/token")
    public @ResponseBody User getUser(@RequestParam("token") String token){
        String email=jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(token);
        User user=userRepository.getUserByUsername(email);
        return user ;
    }
```

[Google Inspect picture for the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvGTn.png)

Comment: You're sending the token in the header and the body. In the backend you're reading the token from the body.

Comment: @ThomasSablik yes I want also to send it in the body to get the user from the token , but to be able to get access to the getUser() function in the backend it must be authenticated and hire come the header

Comment: But `getUser(@RequestParam("token") String token)` doesn't read the token from the header. If you want to add `Bearer` in front of the token add it: `formData.set("token", \`Bearer ${token}\`);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add `Bearer` in front of the token in the body you can add it with:

```
formData.set("token", `Bearer ${token}`);
```